# Run two separate functions on DOMContentLoaded

Tags: javascript, promise, domcontentloaded

I have a website which has two files; `main.js` and `loading.js`

`loading.js` waits for `DOMContentLoaded`, then clears a loading screen cover.

`main.js` also waits for `DOMContentLoaded`, but also waits for `loading.js` to finish its `DOMContentLoaded`, then executes some more code.

I need to write some code (possibly using `Promise`s?) which allows this to happen.

Here is my code:

`loading.js`

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
    var loadingCover = document.querySelector('#loading-cover');
    loadingCover.style.display = 'none';
});
```

`main.js`

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
    /* Wait for loading.js */
    console.log("Do stuff");
});
```

I've done some research with `Promise`s, but I can't wrap my head around how they could work in this situation.

I've tried using a `Promise` which is resolved inside `loading.js`. `main.js` then waits for that `Promise` to be resolved before executing its own code.

Ideally, this would be the code:

`loading.js`

```js
const loadingPromise = new Promise();
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
    var loadingCover = document.querySelector('#loading-cover');
    loadingCover.style.display = 'none';
    loadingPromise.resolve();
});
```

`main.js`

```js
/* Terrible example */
loadingPromise.addEventListener('resolve', () => {
    console.log("Do stuff");
});
```

Comment: You can have 2 handle event attached to the same element and if I remember properly they are executed in order thus should be enough to link first the script for loading.js and later that for main.js  No need promises.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do is by creating a Promise, then saving the `resolve` function to be later called like this:

```js
//
// createPromise() returns an object containing the promise
// itself and the function to be called in order to resolve
// said promise
//
function createPromise() {
    let ret = {}

    ret.promise = new Promise((resolve) => {
        ret.resolve = resolve
    })

    return ret
}

window.main_promise = createPromise()

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
    var loadingCover = document.querySelector('#loading-cover');
    loadingCover.style.display = 'none';

    // add some artificial delay
    setTimeout(window.main_promise.resolve, 1000);
});
```

In loading.js:

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', async () => {
    /* Wait for loading.js */
    await window.main_promise.promise;

    console.log("Do stuff");
});
```

This will block execution of `console.log("Do stuff");` until `window.main_promise.resolve();` is called somewhere in code.

Of course, `main.js` needs to be loaded before `loading.js` in order for this to work.

Comment: This answer is perfect! Thank you. I'll accept asap

Comment: You're quite welcome :-) glad I could help!

Comment: Convoluted solution

Comment: @Nick You don't know what OP is going for, using something that is asynchronous in nature, `Promise`s are the way to go. So no, not convoluted, only if we're dealing with synchronous stuff, then it would be indeed convoluted ; but we don't know that. `Promise`s work regardless, it doesn't matter whether the code is synchronous or not.

Comment: The DomContentLoaded events are asynnchronous by default. The 2 callback are called in an async way thereby the code inside is executed in order by default. No need Promises

Comment: @Nick You're repeating yourself. You don't know what OP is doing in the first callback, so it could (and I assume it is) be asynchronous. You cannot (well, you can, but that's a bit messy and old) deal with that without using Promises.

Comment: Ok, you say the code inside the DomContentLoaded event.    Yes, you are right, if the code inside is asynchronous he  needs Promises or he could load the second script with "dynamic script loading" when the async code inside the first DOMContent loaded handler termined